# node.js + nginx + rails Chat does work on localhost, doesn't work on Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

Chat does work on localhost, doesn't work on Amazon EC2

index.html

```
    <html>
<head>
  <title> Chat with socket.io and node.js</title>
  <style>
    #chat {
      height:500px;
  }
  </style>
<head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center;">CHAT</h1>
  <div id="chat"></div>
  <form id="send-message">
    <input size="35" id="message"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
  </form>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
  var socket = io.connect();
  var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
  var $messageBox = $('#message');
  var $chat = $('#chat');

  $messageForm.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
    $messageBox.val('');
  });

  socket.on('new message', function(data) {
    $chat.append(data + '<br />');
  });
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  server = require('http').createServer(app),
  io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3333);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('send message', function(data){
    io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
  });
});
```

chat example is taken from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNKNYLv2BpQ

node -v
v0.10.13

rails '3.2.13'

when I run -> node app.js
I get -> info  - socket.io started
& when I try to access my_ip:3333    --    no luck.

Any help or hint will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :)   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/layers-server-nodejs.html

"Node.js Application Configuration

The main file run by Node.js must be named server.js and reside in the root directory of the deployed application.

The Node.js application must be set to listen on port 80 (or port 443, if applicable)."